# Display object in just a certain viewport

Tags: c++, opengl

Hi I got 4 viewports and one large that I can switch between now I got an object namely the camera and the cameras target position that I show with rendering a sphere at those locations. I want to show the cameras position in 3 of my viewports but not in the last which is the camera display but at the moment I got an all or nothing scenario.

```
void display(int what)
{
 if(what==5){
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
 camControll();}

 if(what==1){
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluLookAt(75,15,-5,0,5,-5,0,1,0);}

 if(what==2){
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluLookAt(0,110,0,0,0,0,1,0,0);}

 if(what==3){
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluPerspective(45.0f, float(320) / float(240), 0.1f, 100.0f); 
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
 camControll();}

 if(what==4){
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluLookAt(185,75,25,0,28,0,0,1,0);}


 //glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 //glLoadIdentity();
 ////gluLookAt(cos(shared.time) * shared.distance, 10, sin(shared.time) * shared.distance, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);  
 ////ca.orbitYaw(0.05);
 //ca.lookAt();

 glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 drawScene(); // scene that all views should render
 drawCamera(); / camera position that only certain views should render
 glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

I'm thinking that perhaps I could do one sweep for first the 3 viewports and then call glutSwapBuffers() and then do the other viewport without the camera position but some stuttering I previously had was traced to glutSwapBuffers() being called for each viewport so I guess there has to be another way only that I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to render everything before swapping buffers.

As you do it - it is not going to work. Actually, it will work, but not you want.

EDIT

To render to a texture take a look into one of the links [here](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=opengl+render+to+texture&aq=f&aqi=g3g-m2g-v1g-sv1g-v3&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).

After changing a view, render the image for the specific view to a texture. Then for the final image, set the final view and render all 3 textures. Only when the final image is rendered, swap buffers.

On the 2nd thought, it would be much better if you could set the vertices of all objects to render and render whole image in one pass.

Comment: Yes but how should I do it? I view my scene from 3 fixed angles and 1 camera but a few objects in the scene I want only to be seen from the 3 fixed angles.

Comment: @PSilo If it is ok, you could render to one texture in one pass with one view, then to the second texture with another view, and with the 3rd view. Then render these textures into the final image. Only then swap buffers.

Comment: Seems to be along the lines of what I'm thinking of doing but I have ni idea where to start, any tutorials or functions that I should look up? Usually it works for em if I can look up the main opengl function I need to use in the documents and from there google how to use them but I generally have a hard time knowing what functions can do what I need especially if I need new ones that I haven't used before.

Comment: I think I found a tutorial that will be useful with actual code examples. In that they do a render to texture to use as texture for an object but I should be able to hack something together from it, hopefully!